# Redirect to custom page after paypal cancel order WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to redirect  user to a specific page after cancel paypal order using WooCommerce. please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `woocommerce_cancelled_order` hook to redirect on cancel order button. this action will be called on click cancel order by default in WooCommerce.

You can set it in `function.php` file like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cancelled_order','lenura_redirect_to_home');
 function lenura_redirect_to_home() {
    wp_redirect(home_url()); // REDIRECT PATH
 }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks.

Comment: that's for cancelling a pending order. Not when you're on paypal page and want to cancel. But then again, now that I thought about it, the question is not clear about that.

Comment: @Reigel, Have you checked in your PayPal account? Might be there is any option for cancel URL redirect like success URL.

Comment: nope, but on paypal gateway there's a cancel_return... I have added it as an answer here.

Comment: @Ahmad Ginani. I also have installed woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout. when i click cancel button from payapl they redirect me checkout page

Answer (score 0):

It depends which particular page you want him to be redirected. Actually,
I've never seen a plugin for this before. What I suggest is for you to put a cancel order button in one of the woocommerce pages that points to your desired page.

Comment: Thanks. But i am not looking any woocommerece setting after cancel order. from where is set?

Comment: That sounds good, because I really dont know any setting in woo commerce for that. Which page would you like to add that cancel order button?